# Unity IPointerClickHandler new input system UI element (of menu) not triggered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, events

I'm super new to Unity, so this is probably something very stupid that I'm missing since I've seen this question in so many forums but I tried everything that was suggested there + watched tons of tutorials, and still, I cannot make it work :(

I'm creating a main menu for a game, it contains buttons: New game, Load game, etc, and I want a popup to open after I click on the button, and be able to customize the text of the popup based on the specific button.
For example, if I clicked on the "New Game" button -> the popup will say: Are you sure you want to start a new game?

But the OnPointerClick function is never triggered (and of course, I cannot even invoke listeners on my event cause the initial detection of clicking on the button is not working).

This is my project structure:

[image]

I'm using the new input system, using the default input action map.
I added at one time the `Physics Raycaster 2d` to both panels and then switched to `Graphic Raycaster`, but both did not work:

Popup panel:

[image]

MainMenuPanel:

[image]

I also have the EventSystem (as you can see in the project image)

This is the subscription to the event (onClickHander script), that all buttons in `MainMenuPanel` have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class OnClickEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    
    public static event System.Action<GameObject> onClickEnter;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered!!");
        onClickEnter?.Invoke(this.gameObject);

    }
}
```

And this is the subscription to the onClickEnter event, but since it is not invoked in the OnPointerClick on the script above, it's also not work here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PopUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CanvasGroup cg;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        OnClickEventHandler.onClickEnter += DisplayInfo;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        OnClickEventHandler.onClickEnter -= DisplayInfo;
    }

    private void DisplayInfo(GameObject go)
    {
        Debug.Log("in trigger");
    }

}
```

I managed to make the button do something by using the onClick, but this way I cannot know which button triggered it, and also, AFAIK this is not the way you should do it with the new input system:

[image]

If someone can please help me I'll be super thankful, as I'm lost (and has spent almost 5 hours reading materials and watching tutorials).

Also, sometimes I get exceptions that the stacktrace do not mention my code, but /users/bokken which I know is the compilation of Unity. I normally delete the StateCache folder and it's solved, but I'm adding it here in case it can help:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.SceneView.CallOnPreSceneGUI () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:3690)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnPreSceneGUICallbacks (UnityEngine.Rect cameraRect) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2248)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnGUI () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2330)
UnityEditor.SceneView.OnSceneGUI () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2255)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/IMGUIContainer.cs:351)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

And:

```
GUI Error: You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping. Make sure they are balanced.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Thanks!! I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are there `Camera`s on your panels? And why are those `2D Raycaster`? Your one main camera should probably rather do that instead

Comment: @derHugo thanks for your comment!
I'm not sure why the Cameras are there, but they are not active. 
I also removed the 2D raycaster from all the panels and canvases (I only left it on the camera and ignore UI), but still I cannot invoke any click event by clicking on any of the buttons.

Any other ideas? Will appreciate any help!